# C# Asp.NET Get URL Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How I can get the number 68 of the following link? http://localhost:54547/Home/Details/68

I had a DB whit table "Modules", in each module i had content(that is other table in DB) . So when i click in see Contents, it pass a Module ID (that i click) for associate to Content ( localhost:54547/Home/Details/68). When I click for "Create a New Content", i want that the Module ID pass for the next link.

Thanks for help

I am programing in Asp.NET using C#

Comment: Do you have an `Action`?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this from the `RouteData`:

```
var url = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
```

Comment: I want this :
http://localhost:54547/Home/CreateContent/68
After that:
http://localhost:54547/Home/Details/68.

With you code , i get this:
http://localhost:54547/Home/CreateContent?Length=2

Comment: I had a modules, in each module i had contents. So when i click in see models, it pass a Module ID for associate to Content ( localhost:54547/Home/Details/68). When I click for "Create a New Content",  i want that the Module ID pass for the next link.
Its more clear now @geminiousgoel? Thanks for help

Comment: @PedroMoreira man Cool.. I was asking more on whether you need '68' or complete url. And if only the last numeric number then it will be a id and can be get from url (" www.domain.com/Controller/Action/id" ) with this.

Comment: I already can resolve my problem with your code. I only put : Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values. Thanks for help and sorry i am not be so specific, but is my first time using "stackoverflow".
Thanks One more time

Answer (score 0):

Your method in the controller should be like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(int id){
   // You will get value 68 in id

}
```

Comment: how does this solve the problem? the question in itself is not fully complete

Comment: I Want pass 68 for the next link

Comment: @jamiedanq, Yes you are right ! but atleast it should not be downvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's MVC and then 68 is a part of your RouteConfig.cs and in most cases called id.

So you could fetch it like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
   //id is 68
}
```